# What's causing these linker errors? (Visual C++ LNK2005)

Tags: c++, oop, class, linker

I'm a novice programmer, still in the midst of trying to learn C++ and OOP design basics. The project that I've been working on to teach myself is a C++ game that has multiple classes, files, states, etc. However, I keep running into snags with file organization that range from simply struggling with where to create objects to compile-breaking linker errors.

Here's an example of some of the errors that I've been getting:

```
1>SMGA.obj : error LNK2005: "class Engine smgaEngine" (?smgaEngine@@3VEngine@@A) already defined in Engine.obj
1>SplashScreenState.obj : error LNK2005: "class Engine smgaEngine" (?smgaEngine@@3VEngine@@A) already defined in Engine.obj
1>StateManager.obj : error LNK2005: "class StateManager gameStateManager" (?gameStateManager@@3VStateManager@@A) already defined in Engine.obj
1>MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj) : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'msvcrt.lib' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
```

I've looked around online and I've seen a lot of ~similar~ problems that involve bad include guards or the inclusion of .cpp files instead of .h files. But I haven't done that in my code, so I'm at a loss.

Now, I'm guessing that the error is telling me that I'm trying to create the smgaEngine object of the Engine class (and the gameStateManager object of the StateManager class) twice, but I'm not sure why...

The thing that stands out about these two objects (smgaEngine and gameStateManager) is that I declared them in their corresponding class' .h files immediately after the class declaration. Could this be the issue? - They're still within the include guards, and I wasn't too sure about where else to put them in my code... Would this sloppy coding be the cause of linker errors?

Here's one of the suspect classes...

```
#ifndef ENGINE_H
#define ENGINE_H

#include <SDL.h>
#include "Timer.h"

class Engine
{
private:
    static const int screenWidth = 480;
    static const int screenHeight = 270;
    static const int screenBPP = 24;

    bool running;
    SDL_Surface *mainScreen;
    SDL_Event eventHolder;
    Timer fpsTimer;

public:
    Engine();
    ~Engine();

    void init();
    void handleEvents();
    void handleLogic();
    void handleRender();
    void cleanUp();

    SDL_Event *getEvent();

    SDL_Surface *getMainScreen();

    bool isRunning();
    void setRunning(bool tempRunning);
} smgaEngine;

#endif
```

And here's the other one:

```
#ifndef STATEMANAGER_H
#define STATEMANAGER_H

#include "SplashScreenState.h"
#include <vector>

class GameState;

class StateManager
{
private:
    std::vector<GameState*> stateStack;

    SplashScreenState *splashState;

public:
    StateManager();
    ~StateManager();

    void init();

    void changeState( GameState *tempNextState );
    void addState( GameState *tempNextState );
    void removeState();

    //returns the back() element of the stateStack vector..
    GameState* getTopState();

    void handleEvents();
    void handleLogic();
    void handleRender();
} gameStateManager;

#endif
```

I've been trying my best to learn C++ and OOP, but I've really been struggling. It seems that every time I attempt to make clean code with encapsulated classes, I end up with a confusing mess. I'm trying to prevent a high degree of class coupling, but I often end up with either linker errors or a lack of ability to communicate between classes... Is it creation of class instance objects within the header files that is causing these errors or is it something else? And if that is the cause of my linker errors, then where should I be creating these objects?

Answer (score 6):

You have defined two global variables, `smgaEngine` and `gameStateManager` in your header files, and you have included those header files in two (or more) source files. So you get multiple definition errors. Include guards don't stop header files being included twice in different source files (how could they?) they stop header files being included twice in the *same* source file.

You're quite close to the correct answer (at least you have a good understanding of the problem). The right way is this

```
// header file Engine.h
class Engine
{
};

extern Engine smgaEngine;

// in one source file (say Engine.cpp)
Engine smgaEngine;
```

What you have now is a *declaration* in the header file (`extern` makes it a declaration), but a *definition* in the source file. You can have as many declarations as you like (as long as they are consistent) but you must have only one definition. So for global variables put declarations in the header file and put a definition in one of the source files.

Comment: Ah hah! Thanks so much for the clear and detailed answer, John. I should probably be avoiding global variables anyway! ^^ Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to help. 'I should probably be avoiding global variables anyway!'. Well that's design issue, you'll get a million different opinions on questions like that, and none of them will be definitive. For OOP and design issues I would advise to keep it simple (at least while you are learning) and go with what seems instinctively right to you. If globals seem to fit your needs and you don't see the downsides, then go with them. If later you find that the globals are causing problems, then at least you will have a better understanding of the issues.

Comment: Awesome advice all round, +1 :)